# How to approach solving Webpack ERROR / WARNING logs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I was recently introduced to a project where it is leveraging the React Boilerplate [located here](https://www.reactboilerplate.com/):

After getting the initial project "set up" taken care of, upon running `yarn`, I'm greeted with a large amount of `WARNING` and `ERROR` output. As some may know, it won't necessarily "fail" [due to these errors](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7494), which may be the reason that the end of the `yarn` installation, I'm greeted with "`✨  Done in 45.17s.`"

I've listed one of each instance (Warning/Error) below – if you'd like to review a complete list of them, [use this link](https://pastebin.com/tf7rMhPt).

**Warning –**

```
WARNING in ./~/win-release/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '~/ProjectDir/node_modules/win-release'
 @ ./~/win-release/index.js 26:31-55
 @ ./~/os-name/index.js
 @ ./~/snyk/lib/analytics.js
 @ ./~/snyk/lib/monitor.js
 @ ./~/snyk/lib/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps
```

**Error –**

```
ERROR in ./~/joi/lib/string.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '~/ProjectDir/node_modules/joi/lib'
 @ ./~/joi/lib/string.js 3:10-24
 @ ./~/joi/lib/index.js
 @ ./~/nsp/lib/check.js
 @ ./~/nsp/lib/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps
```

**Question:**
Since I'm relatively new to this project (and webpack), I'm wondering how I "should" perceive these errors and how I may isolate the cause and resolve them going forward. I may be approaching this incorrectly, however, I'm trying to understand *why* they have been introduced and (in some circumstances) I'm the only one incurring the Warning/Errors.

Any advice as to why, what, or how to resolve these issues, would be greatly appreciated. I've done a great deal of google-ing and haven't found much aligned with the current circumstances.

**On-going solution exploration:**

**1)** *As suggested by @proti*

```
$ npm cache clean

npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     ~/.npm/_logs/2017-10-24T18_03_30_905Z-debug.log

$ npm cache verify

Cache verified and compressed (~/.npm/_cacache):
Content verified: 0 (0 bytes)
Index entries: 0
Finished in 0.01s
```

**2)** Attempted to run a `internals/scripts/analyze.js` ([source](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/internals/scripts/analyze.js)) through Node, which in turn generated a `stats.json` file, [which I leveraged here](http://webpack.github.io/analyse/). It appears isn't reporting any of these issues, in fact, it claims it's only incurring a single warning? Is this stuff purposely complicated..?

[image]

Comment: More technical information:`node=8.6.0 & npm=5.3.0`

Comment: I would start from removing the ./node_modules folder than `npm cache clean` and than `npm install`. I was using yarn recently but I switched back to npm as yarn generates a few errors after the upgrade, try npm instead yarn.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @proti – I've updated the initial description to reflect this.

Comment: It appears that `node` and `yarn` are installing the appropriate dependencies without too much feedback. It's only when the installation process arrives at the `webpack` process (baked in the `node ./internals/scripts/dependencies.js`) that it begins output the endless stream of "complaints". Any other advice? Happy to share the `dependencies.js` file if it is necessary for direction towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> This has been addressed by the support of the webpack issue tracker/community –
>   https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5878.

**Solution:**
Introduce the `stats` object with the value/pair for `errors: false` and `warnings: false`.

To better understand the object, see here – https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/

If anybody would like to define the "true" WHY this required hiding and now addressing, I'm happy to take this offline.